# How do I replace the name of a node with a key in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to use a key to find the corresponding node to a different node from a different level. I do not understand how to replace the node name with a key without getting an error.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
     <xsl:key name = "coursesbygrade" match = "course" use = "grade" />
     <xsl:key name = "profbyid" match = "prof" use = "@instid" />
    <xsl:output method = "html" />
    <xsl:template match = "/">
    <html>
     <head><link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "./courses.css" /></head>
     <body>
     <div class = 'container'>
     <table>
   <xsl:for-each select = "//course[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('coursesbygrade', grade)[1])]">
   <xsl:sort select = "grade" />
   <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select = "grade" /></td>
     <td>
     <xsl:for-each select = "key('coursesbygrade', grade)">
      <xsl:value-of select = "dept" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select = "num" />
      <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select = "//(key('profbyid', 'num[@refinstid]'))/name" />
      <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Have any input/output XML? Can you include the rest of your XSLT so its valid?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, such as what you are trying to achieve, or even what the error message actually is, I would guess your issue is with this line

```
<xsl:value-of select = "//(key('profbyid', 'num[@refinstid]'))/name" />
```

You don't need to use `//` here for a start, as the key returns the actual node, so you don't have to then 'search' for it in the hierarchy. Also, you have apostrophes around the second parameter in the key, which means it will be looking for a string literal. I am guessing you really want to search using the value of the node (or attribute).

This is (probably) the statement you need

```
<xsl:value-of select = "key('profbyid', num/@refinstid)/name" />
```

So, it gets the value of the **refinstid** attribute of the **num** element, and looks up the matching **prof** node using the key, and then returns its **name**.